# How to pass JSON string into MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried to pass JSON string into MySQL DB with PHP. But into DB table inserts "Array", and in the debug.txt file inserts normal string.

```
    require("conf/mysql.php");

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $json = $_REQUEST;
    $obj = $json;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO server_info (`data`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($obj)."')";
    file_put_contents("debug.txt", $obj);
    if (!$result = $mysqli->query($sql)) file_put_contents("db.log", "DB failure while executing query\n$mysqli->error\n$sql");
}
else
    die("Illegal method!");
```

Debug.txt

```
{"Map":"gm_metro_nekrasovskaya_line_v3","PlayerCount":1.0,"Wagons":0.0,"MaxWagons":6.0,"MaxPlayers":15.0,"ServerName":"Verona General Metrostroi","Players":[{"SteamID":"STEAM_0:1:57045033","Nick":"thescs","Rank":"superadmin","Time":8776.0,"Position":"Депо"}]}
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is an array. `mysqli_real_escape_STRING` takes a string. `file_put_contents` takes a string or an array ([s. documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)). The file_put_contents function converts the array automatically to a readable string version of the array. mysqli_real_escape_string don't do this.

Solution: convert the array to a string using `json_encode` ([Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php))

Answer (score 0):

use json_encode to convert JSON to string in php
`$sql = "INSERT INTO server_info (`data`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,json_encode($obj))."')";`

Make sure the field 'data' can store the entire JSON string e.g: TEXT or LONGTEXT as it data type